# fancybox code delay on opening

Tags: fancybox, delay

I have the following code

```
               jQuery(document).ready(function() {


                jQuery("#popup-form-signin").fancybox({
                     'showCloseButton'  : false,
                });

                <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['popup_subscribe'])) :
                        $_SESSION['popup_subscribe'] = 1;
                ?>  
                        jQuery("#popup-form-subscribe").fancybox({
                             'closeClick'  : false,
                        }).click();   
                        setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("#popup-form-subscribe").click();
}, 20000);                 

                <?php endif; ?>
```

I need to add a timeout to delay the popup
i found the code

```
    setTimeout( function() {$('#popup-form-subscribe').trigger('click'); },20000);
```

but i dont know where to put it

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove ".click()" when initialising fancyBox, e.g.:

```
jQuery("#popup-form-subscribe").fancybox({
    'closeClick'  : false,
});

setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("#popup-form-subscribe").trigger('click');
}, 20000);
```